# Inconsistent Behavior Of futures.ProcessPoolExecutor

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrency, future

In considering the following code:

```
from concurrent import futures
import os
import signal


with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as ex:
    print('getting the pid for one worker')
    f1 = ex.submit(os.getpid)
    pid1 = f1.result()

    print('killing process {}'.format(pid1))
    os.kill(pid1, signal.SIGHUP)

    print('submitting another task')
    f2 = ex.submit(os.getpid)
    try:
        pid2 = f2.result()
    except futures.process.BrokenProcessPool as e:
        print('could not start new tasks: {}'.format(e))
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```

There is an inconsistency in the output. From the docs I read it's supposed to have the behavior of:

*"If something happens to one of the worker processes to cause it to exit unexpectedly, the ProcessPoolExecutor is considered “broken” and will no longer schedule tasks."*

That script is supposed to exemplify that. Instead, if I run the code several times, I get the following output:

```
(bot-LP2ewIkY) ⋊> ~/w/p/b/bot on master ⨯ python brokenPool.py                                                                                                                                                                   18:54:55
getting the pid for one worker
killing process 4373
submitting another task
could not start new tasks: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.
(bot-LP2ewIkY) ⋊> ~/w/p/b/bot on master ⨯ python brokenPool.py                                                                                                                                                                   18:54:56
getting the pid for one worker
killing process 4443
submitting another task
could not start new tasks: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.
(bot-LP2ewIkY) ⋊> ~/w/p/b/bot on master ⨯ python brokenPool.py                                                                                                                                                                   18:54:57
getting the pid for one worker
killing process 4514
submitting another task  <----- (No exception thrown after this)
```

As you can see (Arrow points to what shouldn't happen), it only throws an exception part of the time. Is this a bug?

Note: Here is the related question I was trying to get answered that lead me to discover this: [ProcessPoolExecutor, BrokenProcessPool handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52617401/processpoolexecutor-brokenprocesspool-handling)

Update: Reported to Python: https://bugs.python.org/issue34877